# How to override System Status Bar Tiles (Wifi, Bluetooth, Data and Location etc) with custom icon and colored background etc?

Tags: android, system, android-app-quick-setting

I am working on application wherein I want custom quick setting features, i.e. custom icon with improved UI and background color along-with gradient background of the quick setting tiles to override the current system quick setting tiles (Wifi, Bluetooth, location etc).

Exploring Github Repositories only got me to how we can add custom tile and handle its click etc but that is not sufficient for me in this case.

My app features are to convert this:- [Normal Quick Setting Tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clDn1.png)
INTO this [Wanted Quick Setting Tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPQ0u.png).

Is there any one who can guide me to where I can find related data to utilize and obtained the desired features. BIG THANKS IN ADVANCE!

I have worked a lot but could not find any clue. Try the following repos from github:-
1.[Screen Share Tile](https://github.com/npes87184/ScreenShareTile)
2.[Android Show Taps QS Tile](https://github.com/VarunS2002/Android-Show-Taps-QS-Tile)
3. [Navigation QS Tile](https://github.com/00RohitRoshan/Navigation-QS-Tile) and Many more.

I also searched on stack overflow but couldn't succeeded to get the required data...

1. [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858950/how-to-modify-aosp-systemui-in-android-pie-9-0-programmatically)
2. [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807893/how-to-add-my-own-item-to-system-status-bar-in-android-near-wifi-bluetooth)